# do I need to handle UAC if an application is trying to connect to internet?

Tags: windows, security, winapi, windows-7, uac

I guess uac is needed if I write to directories others than Documents, if I change the registry or if I disable system devices, handle firewall, things like that. But what if the app tries to connect to internet - 80,443 port? what are the limitations uac places? 
10x!

Comment: This is not a UAC issue. It's a Windows firewall issue. The firewall has to be opened for your application in some circumstances; those circumstances depend on what your app is specifically trying to do (and when).

Comment: thank you, this is kind of circular argument as I now read that for a firewall change to occur - you need UAC. But then again, you're right.

Comment: Read again what I said. And then read what @vcsjones said in his answer.

Answer (score 4):

UAC normally does not affect making internet connections, assuming the port is not blocked by Firewall. A *firewall* change may require UAC elevation, but the actual act of opening a connection on a port does not. A program should be able to open connection and listen on port 80 or 443 without issue, assuming nothing else is occupying those ports.

Comment: thank you...I just read some complaints online that some people have an internet UAC issue - but it's due to...hardware problems/drivers and uac not approving some drivers?? what i seem to comprehend...

Comment: +1. That's what I said; you said it better (and as an answer). :)